# PropertyChanged Returns null After Initial Binding for Datagrids

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

My PropertyChanged is working fine for all the objects I have on my page which are not bound to Datagrids, which work correctly on the initial binding, but then lose said binding when I modify or reset the bound Property.

Note that I have tried using ObservableCollection and had the same result.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="263" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,120,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" Name="dg_Display" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="313">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FileName}" Header="File Name" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date}" Header="Date" />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Stack}" Header="Stack" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```cs
private List<StackModel.Display> m_files;
public List<StackModel.Display> Files
{
    get { return m_files ?? (m_files = StackModel.ListFiles(Path)); }
    set
    {
        m_files = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Files"));
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
private DelegateCommand m_directory;
public ICommand DirectoryCommand { get { return m_directory ?? (m_directory = new DelegateCommand(Directory)); } }

private void Directory()
{
    Files = StackModel.ListFiles(Path);
}
```

```cs
public List<Display> ListFiles(string path)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.xlsx");

    return files.Select(fileEntry => new Display {Date = fileEntry.LastWriteTime, FileName = fileEntry.Name, Stack = true}).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is modifying or resetting the property?

Answer (score 2):

Try instead of

```
public List<StackModel.Display> Files
{
   ..
}
```

use

```
public ObservableCollection<StackModel.Display> Files
{
   ..
}
```

As much as I understood, your problem is that on load all data present in collection loaded correctly, but after if you clear that collection, remove or add new items the change has not it's impact on UI.

[ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) should resolve this problem for you.

Should work..

Comment: *forgot to put this in there, my mistake.  I've tried this with ObservableCollection as well- same problem.
I'm reasonably certain that the issue is that there's no subscriber to the property.

Comment: The last edit shows, it's a simple case of setting the property to a new value

Comment: MAY BE I understood your problem. I saw that you assign a *new* instance of the collection to Files property. WPF Binding keeps track on exact reference of the collection it binds (based on my expirience). Try instead of assigning just a new collection, **clear** and **populate** Files collection with a new values. May be just by using AddRange function and use ObservableCollection, naturaly.

Comment: Yup, that works, thanks.  Add that as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Aside: do you know, is there a particular reason that I can't just set it to a new instance?

Comment: Don't remember I ever saw some article on prove of this concept. Just something I noticed during my work. Not a prove, naturally...

Comment: The idea I always have is that even if you specify in XAML a property *name* , WPF binding stores a *reference* to that object. In your case first you store in binding your list and after even if you assign to property a new collection, the binding still stores inside a reference to the old one.